# Как вызвать процедуру в анонимном блоке с помощью declare?

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-procedures, хранимые-процедуры

Допустим есть процедура

```
create or replace procedure get_sum(first_num integer,
                                    second_num integer) is
res_sum integer; 
begin
  res_sum := first_num + second_num;
  dbms_output.put_line(res_sum);
end;
```

Мне нужно, что бы я мог её через анонимный блок вызвать через declare, как правильно написать?

Comment: Вам нужно функцию get_sum вызвать через анонимный блок? т.к. declare это он и есть

Comment: declare
begin
   get_sum(1, 2);
end;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare
   procedure start_get_sum(f in integer,
                           s in integer ) is
   begin
      get_sum(f, s);
   end start_get_sum;
begin
    start_get_sum(1,2); -- если хочется именно через declare, хотя не ясно зачем именно так?
    get_sum(1,2);       -- а чего не так?
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

> вызвать через declare

Никак. Через само ключевое слово `DECLARE` вообще ничего не вызывыется.

Ключевое слово `DECLARE` начинает декларативную секцию анонимного блока, заканчивающуюся ключевым словом `BEGIN`. В этой секции можно только объявить переменные, константы, внутренние функции и процедуры. Для инициализации переменных (опционально) и констант могут быть вызваны только функции.

Comment: Точно никак? А как тогда вызвать процедуру/функцию, которая в пакете, но не в спеке, т.е. она же скрыта получается и если вызвать её просто через анонимный блок, то будет ошибка, что типа процедура/функция не объявлена.

Comment: _Точно никак?_ как сформулировано в вопросе - _в анонимном блоке с помощью declare_, то точно не получится. _А как тогда вызвать процедуру/функцию, которая в пакете, но не в спеке_, а) какое это отноение имеет к текущему вопросу? б) их можно вызвать только внутри других процедур или функций пакета.

Comment: @Frelay Отвечая я принял во внимание ваш предыдущий вопрос, то есть, исходил из того, что вы понимаете, как вызывать процедуры в анонимном блоке. Поэтому, мне (и др. комментаторам) осталось непонятным, что зннчит или зачем _вызвать через declare_. Попробуйте как-то переформулировать постановку вопроса,  пояснить, что вы делаете, каковы цели вашей задачи в целом. Например, если вдруг станет возможным _вызвать через declare_, что вы достигните этим?